# Pass a cell range as a variable and copy data using a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

Im trying to create a function in VBA that copies data from one sheet to another based on the input to the function. However, I'm having great difficulty in using the arguments to the function in the actual function itself.

Below is my code: as you can see, the range I want is hardcoded in for now, and this works! But I cannot get it to accept the range I pass as an argument to the function. What am I doing wrong?

data should be in place of range(F35:F65) and target should be in place of range(C6)

```
Function Copytranspose(data As Range, target As Range)

    
    
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("F35:F65").Copy
    
    Worksheets("Totalizers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("C6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        
End Function

Sub tempo()
Call Copytranspose(Range("F35:F65"), Range("C6"))

End Sub
```

Comment: You dont seem to be using the arguments, you are passing in the args and they are also hard coded.   It would be data.copy and target.pastespecial.  Or `target.resize(data.rows.count,data.columns.count).value=data.value`

Comment: You should also add sheet references to your arguments, and no need to activate/select things.

Comment: Yes, they are hard-coded at the moment, just to test if the rest works, when I use data.copy it does not work and throws an exception @Nathan_Sav

Comment: Yeah, one of my earlier itterations was the code like:
`    Worksheets("Data").Range("F35:F65").Copy
    
    
    Worksheets("Totalizers").Range("C6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False`

Which is still the same, it works when I hardcode the range, not when I use the argument. I'm probably not passing the argument correctly but can't figure out how I should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Values of a Range

**Two HardCoded Worksheets (Range Address (String) Parameters)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRange( _
        ByVal SourceRangeAddress As String, _
        ByVal DestinationFirstCellAddress As String, _
        Optional ByVal DoTranspose As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SourceRangeAddress)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Totalizers")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DestinationFirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    If DoTranspose Then
        Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Columns.Count, srg.Rows.Count)
        drg.Value = Application.Transpose(srg.Value)
    Else
        Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
        drg.Value = srg.Value
    End If
        
End Sub

Sub tempo()
    
    ' Either transpose...
    CopyRange "F35:F65", "C6", True ' 'C6:AG6'
    ' ... or do not transpose:
    'CopyRange "F35:F65", "C6" ' 'C6:C36'

End Sub
```

**Any Ranges (Range Parameters)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRange( _
        ByVal srg As Range, _
        ByVal dfCell As Range, _
        Optional ByVal DoTranspose As Boolean = False)

    Dim drg As Range
    
    If DoTranspose Then
        Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Columns.Count, srg.Rows.Count)
        drg.Value = Application.Transpose(srg.Value)
    Else
        Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
        drg.Value = srg.Value
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub tempo()
    
    ' Either transpose...
    CopyRange Range("F35:F65"), Range("C6"), True ' 'C6:AG6'
    ' ... or do not transpose:
    'CopyRange Range("F35:F65"), Range("C6") ' 'C6:C36'
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work as intended as the two ranges are on different sheets. I must say I don't understand VBA enough to decipher what is happening here. (I also need the values to be copied instead of the formula's hence the special paste). I however still don't understand why I just can pass something like "F35:F65" as a string or something, and just use that in an expressions like Range(MyVar).copy

Comment: I've posted another solution.

Comment: This works! thanks a ton! Altough I must say I still don't understand why the whole resize thing is needed, or why my code wouldn't work. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: This [Resize business](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) is called *Copying by Assignment*. You're basically 'saying'  the range in the destination is equal to the range in the source. The catch is that this only works correctly if the ranges are of the same size. So you resize the destination first cell to the size of the source. This is the most efficient (fastest) way to copy only values. Most often you don't even notice that anything has happened. The selection hasn't changed i.e. you don't end up with a selection like you do when using `PasteSpecial`.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up A lot! I would up-vote your answer, but I don't have the privileges yet...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Sub CopyData(sourceRange As Excel.Range, targetRange As Excel.Range)

targetRange.Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Value = sourceRange.Value

End Sub

Sub TestCopyData()
    
CopyData Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a3"), Sheets("sheet1").Range("q1")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use a sub here and not a function? It was my (limited) understanding that I need a function because I want to call it many times within one click of a button.  What I have already works, I just don't know how use the argument instead of the hard-coded range

Comment: Functions return a value, your function doesnt, so i've used a sub.  The answer shows how to use the arguments, and how to do the job better?  i'll leave it to you then.   Cheers

Comment: I don't understand your code all to well, could you explain the second line? why resize it? and what does resize do?

Comment: Try using the help it will go in better reading that, than me explaining.  Resize, resizes a range.